# A flaw inside app when using recyclerview to load documents from firestore in kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view to load documents from firestore. Now my recycler view lists has three buttons. One of the button name is notify. When I click notify button(`btn_notify`) I want to make the button visibity to gone using `holder.button.visibility = View.GONE`. But what happens is that when I change the button visibility to gone, the clicked button visibility changes to gone. At the same time the other recycler view lists button visibility also changes to gone. Why this error is happening.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

````
package com.example.bloodbankcompany.recyclerview


import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.*
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.lang.Exception

const val TOPIC = "/topics/myTopic"

class MyAdapter2(private val userList: ArrayList<User2>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder>(){
var id: String = ""
    private lateinit var userArrayList: ArrayList<User2>


    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    val TAG = "MyAdapter2"

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item2,parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)



    }
//
//    interface OnItemClickListener {
//        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
//    }



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter2.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
//        holder.bind( position ,onItemClickListener)
        val user:User2 = userList[position]
        holder.name.text= user.name
        holder.phone.text= user.phone
        holder.address.text =user.address
        holder.bloodGroup.text= user.bloodgroup
        holder.id.text = user.id
        holder.status.text= user.status
        holder.donatedby.text = user.donatedBy.toString()
        val statust = user.status?.trim()
        val requester_name = user.name
        val requester_no = user.phone


        holder.emailn.text= user.email

        val idp: String? =user.id
        val phonen: String? =user.phone
        val emailt: String? = user.email

holder.button.setOnClickListener {
            holder.button.visibility = View.GONE

           
           

            val washingtonre = mFireStore.collection("applicationForm").document("$idp")

                washingtonre.update("status","Verified").addOnCompleteListener {
                    holder.status.text = "Verified"

                    val title = "New blood donation request."
                    val message = "Please contact $requester_name at $requester_no."
                    //val recipientToken = etToken.text.toString()
                    if(title.isNotEmpty() && message.isNotEmpty()) {
                        PushNotificationNotif(
                            NotificationDataNotif(title, message),
                            TOPIC
                            //   recipientToken
                        ).also {
                            sendNotification(it)
                        }
                    }

                }








        }



        holder.phonen.setOnClickListener {

            val context=holder.button.context

            val intent1 = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
            intent1.data = Uri.parse("tel:" + phonen)
            context.startActivity(intent1)

        }
     holder.bemail.setOnClickListener {

         val context1=holder.button.context
         val intent= Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
         intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:" + emailt)
         intent.type = "text/plain"
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailt)
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " ")

         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ")

         intent.setType("message/rfc822")

         try {
//             context1.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose email Client"))
             context1.startActivity(intent)

         } catch (e: Exception){

         }


     }


    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private fun sendNotification(notification: PushNotificationNotif) = CoroutineScope(
        Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            val response = RetrofitInstanceNotif.api.postNotification(notification)
            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: ${Gson().toJson(response)}")
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, response.errorBody().toString())
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size

    }

    public class MyViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){


//        fun bind(position: Int, listener: OnItemClickListener) {
//            button.setOnClickListener { v -> listener.onItemClick(position) }
//        }

        val name : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvfirstname1)
        val phone :TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvphone11)
        val address : TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvaddress1)
        val bloodGroup: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvbloodg1)
        val id: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvid)
        val status: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstatus1)
//        val donationsta: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdonated1)
        var io: String? = ""
        val button: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_notify)
        val phonen: Button =itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_phone1)
        val emailn: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvemail1)
        val bemail: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_email1)
        val donatedby: TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvdonated1)





    }
} ```


/** This is the recyclerview activity code

package com.example.bloodbankcompany.recyclerview

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Adapter
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.MyAdapter
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.R
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.User1
import com.example.bloodbankcompany.User2
import com.google.firebase.firestore.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_blood_application_form.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main2.*
import java.lang.NullPointerException

class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userArrayList: ArrayList<User2>
    private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter2
    private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


    var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
//        setupActionBar()

        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        userArrayList= arrayListOf()
        myAdapter =MyAdapter2(userArrayList)


        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter

        EventChangeListener()


    }



    private fun EventChangeListener() {
         try {
             mFireStore.collection("applicationForm").addSnapshotListener(object :
                 EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
                 override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                     if (error != null) {
                         Log.e("firestore error", error.message.toString())
                     }
                 try {
                     for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                         if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                             userArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(User2::class.java))
                         }
//                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,userArrayList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                     }
                 } catch (e:NullPointerException){

                 }
                     myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                 }

             })
         } catch (e:NullPointerException){

         }


    }

}


  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/loob8.jpg
````

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: Probably your another `button` is constrained to the `btn_notify`, so when `btn_notify` is gone, another button jumps somewhere you cant see

Comment: What is wrong is that When I press notify button(that button dsappears) in one of the tiles of recyclerview other button in some other tiles in also disappears. I only want  the clicked button to disappear. Onclicklistener is set  in `holder.button.setOnClickListener` . As my documents get loaded from the firestore some of the notify buttons also disappears.